# Last single full post in home page, excerpts in blog list

Tags: homepage, frontpage

**What would be the best approach to show only the very last single full post in the home page and in blog page the full (paged) list of blogs showing only its excerpts?**

I'm thinking of 2 different ways of getting it: one is (A) choosing 'static page' for frontpage, the other one (B) choosing 'last entries'.

**CASE A (static page)**

I'd need a script to load full last post content. In 'options > reading' it'd be set to show excerpts and, for instance, 10 posts per page maximum

**CASE B (last entries)**

I'd need a script to force home page to show only one post (it'd be the last one) and do it in full. Same as in Case A, in 'options > reading' it'd be set to show excerpts and, for instance, 10 posts per page maximum.

.

Right now I'm using Case B. I already got a script inserted in functions.php in order to show only the last post (one). Still I need to force it to be shown in full (or to show the rest as excerpts by default).

The script I got it from here. https://www.webhostinghero.com/change-number-of-posts-on-homepage/

Anyone to help finding the easiest more straightforward solution?

TIA,
hip

Comment: create a page using a custom page template and set it as the static page

Comment: Thank yoy @inarilo but I don't want a static front page but to show the whole very last post at each moment

Comment: the page will be static but the content will be dynamic. create a page template that displays the latest post and then create an empty page (it can have content of you wish, remember to display the content in your template if so), selecting that page template.

Comment: Thank you @inarilo I'll go then for option A (static page for front page). No I need to know how to " create a page template that displays the latest post". I'll keep on searching or waiting for someone to throw some light within this thread.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/ - you can create or modify front-page.php or you can create a separate page template. check the hierarchy used for pages as well. use https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts with `posts_per_page` set to 1 to get the latest post. the code for displaying posts is given as well. it's possible that your theme has a template part file for a single post, in which case you can just drop that into the loop after setting up the post data https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/ hope this helps :)

Comment: as a starting point use the code from front-page.php if it exists or copy page.php, and if you modiy files, keep a backup ideally if you replace files you'd create a child theme so that when the original theme is updated your files will not be overwritten.

Comment: Thank you. I may search for it. I believe this post could be closed as 'solved' now. Is there any way I can rate you? Ty

Comment: if you think this constitutes the answer you wanted, i can copy it to an answer and you can accept it.

Comment: ok, that makes sense

Comment: so have you got it set up? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create or modify front-page.php or you can create a page template that displays the latest post and then create an empty page (it can have content of you wish, remember to display the content in your template if so) and select that page template. In case of the latter, name it according to the page [hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy). In case of the former, if your theme already has a front-page.php, it is better to create a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) instead of overwriting the file directly.

Use [get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) with `'posts_per_page' => 1` to get the latest post. The code for displaying posts is given in the link. It's possible that your theme has a [template part](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part) file for a single post, in which case you can just drop that into the loop after calling `setup_postdata`.

As a starting point, copy the code from front-page.php if it exists, or else page.php.